# How to get the values from a form before_update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I need to get the values from a form and adjust it before the form updates.

What I have is a Project and a project has many Main Groups and Main Groups has many Trades.

So before I save a form, I want to check if there are any values for the cost input in Trades and if there are, the sum of this should overwrite the cost value for Main Groups.

So here is what I have:

```
class MainGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project

    has_many :trades
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :trades, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true 

    private

    before_update do
        if (self.trades.sum(:cost) != 0)
            self.cost = self.trades.sum(:cost)
        else
            self.cost = self.cost       
        end
    end

end
```

The only problem is that it uses the current values in the DB instead of the new ones in the form.

Thanks.

Comment: You can write a separate method and call it through (say `@main_group`) object. Before that, you have to set `@main_group.trades` to the value to be updated, then **self** will have the values from **form** not from **DB**

Comment: Hi, thanks I am a rails noob but this makes sense, kind of.

Answer (score 1):

```
before_save :update_cost_from_trades

private

def update_cost_from_trades  
  unless trades.sum(:cost).is_zero?  
    self.cost = trades.sum(:cost)
  end  
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I am getting an undefined method `is_zero?' for 7000:Fixnum. I assume that I just need to give the trade cost fields a default value of 0 which I tried but the error is still persisting.

Comment: I got it to work using unless trades.sum(:cost).is_blank? but it still uses values from the DB and not the form.

Comment: Yes, I think cost data type is integer or float, in that case default value should be 0 and null false.